# Notificaciones con android firebase

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification

Buen día tengo un problema. Me gustaría que me ayudaran ya que estoy implementando **notificaciones push** con **firebase** en **android** la notificación tiene el titulo el body y una imagen que envío desde **php** mi código es el siguiente:

```
function.php

        function enviarNotificacion($result, $msj, $title, $photo)
        {

            $registrationIds = [0];
            $x = 0;
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
            {
                $registrationIds[$x] = $r->token;
            print("                /               ");
            print $r->token;
                $x++;
            }

            // prep the bundle
    //        $msg = [
      //          'title'         =>  $title,
        //        'body'          =>  $msj,
          //      'sound'         => 'default',
            //    'vibrate'       =>'1'
    $msg = array ("body" => $msj , "title" => $title, "sound" => 'default',"vibrate" =>'1');
            //];
    $dat = [
         'imagen' => $photo
    ];
            $fields = [
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
                'notification'              => $msg,
                'data'    => $dat
            ];
     $headers = [
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ];
            $fields = json_encode( $fields );

            //apt-get install -y php5-curl

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
            $result = curl_exec($ch );
            curl_close( $ch );
            session_start();
            exitosamente";

            return $result;
        }
```

**clase en java:**

```
notification.java

    public class NoticiasFirebaseMessaginService extends FirebaseMessagingService 
    {
     private static final String TAG = "NoticiasMessaginService";
        private   Bitmap image ;
         public  String img ;

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
            Log.d(TAG, "from "+ remoteMessage.getFrom());
            Noticia noticia = new Noticia();
            noticia.setTipo(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            noticia.setDescripcion(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            //noticia.setPhoto(remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon());
            img = remoteMessage.getData().get("imagen");
            showNotification(noticia);

        }

        public void showNotification(Noticia noticia)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrincipalActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent
                    = PendingIntent.getActivity( this,0 ,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Uri defaultSoundUri  = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            try {
                image = Picasso.with(this).load(img).get();
                Log.i(TAG,"el el try");
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.i(TAG,"el el catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           NotificationCompat.Builder  notificationBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_sin_fondo)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.useragricultor))
                    .setContentTitle(noticia.getTipo())
                    .setContentText(noticia.getDescripcion())
                    .setStyle(new  NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image).setSummaryText(noticia.getDescripcion()))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{0,300,200,300})
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                     NotificationManager notificationManager
                    = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

        }

    }
```

Cuando la *app* esta abierta la notificación me llega de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si la **app** esta cerrada solo llega algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se en dónde esta el error o que hay que hacer para que la notificación llegue de estando cerrada la app de la misma forma que cuando esta abierta
gracias a los que puedan ayudarme me sería muy útil.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En la notificación precisamente estas definiendo un estilo el cual muestra la imagen al expandir la notificación, elimina la imagen que carga mediante el método `bigPicture()`:

```
    //.setStyle(new  NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image).setSummaryText(noticia.getDescripcion()))
.setStyle(new  NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().setSummaryText(noticia.getDescripcion()))
```

El problema es que si usas  [**NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html) y no deseas la imagen, visualizarías algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te aconsejo usar mejor  [**BigTextStyle()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html)

```
 .setStyle(new  NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setSummaryText(noticia.getDescripcion()))
```

---

En cuanto a tu pregunta:

> No se en dónde esta el error o que hay que hacer para que la
>   notificación llegue de estando cerrada la app de la misma forma que
>   cuando esta abierta.

Si deseas que se muestre de la misma forma es simplemente no asignar un estilo

```
//.setStyle(new  NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image).setSummaryText(Summary noticia.getDescripcion()))
```

---

**Actualización:**

**El usuario desea que la notificación se muestre expandida al ser recibida por el dispositivo, esto no es posible hasta el día de hoy**, las notificaciones son recibidas de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y posteriormente puedes interactuar con ella, ya sea dando clic o expandiendola, si es que lo permite el estilo definido.

Comment: he probado lo que me acaba de comentar y nada no e solucionado mi problema pero investigando un poco e leído que hay que crear un Service para que esto funcione pero la verdad no tengo ni la remota idea de como encapsular mi código con el Service no se si puedas ayudarme  :(

Comment: Lo que no deseas es que se muestre la imagen al expandir la notificacion?

Comment: la imagen ya se esta mostrando eso esta correcto lo que pasa es que cuando la app esta cerrada la imagen no se muestra solo carga una notificación como la de el segundo ejemplo y no como la de el primero para que pase lo de el primero hay que tener la app abierta y eso es lo que no quiero lo que  quiero que si la app esta cerrada me cargue igual la imagen

Comment: @Cediendo_Lo_Aprendido amigo, **las push notifications siempre llegan colapsadas o como el ejemplo que indicas.** Tu puedes decidir expandir posteriormente la notificación, pero como se muestra en la segunda imagen es correcto.